# Force Service Reference to generate new class instead of "reusing" it

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a WCF project that I'm referencing from another project. My WCF has this defined as a method:

```
public MyClass getClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

MyClass is in a commonly shared library, so when I add the web reference for my service, it simply uses the MyClass class in the shared library. However, for various reasons, I need to force it NOT to use that, and instead generate it's own internal class structure to match (as would happen when MyClass is NOT in a shared library.)

Short of removing it from the shared library, is there a way to force this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While configuring the service reference, you can select to re-use types in certain libraries instead of "all". This way, you can include all but the library you don't want to re-use:

[image]

Comment: Nice, I've never even noticed that option in there :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Configure the Service Reference from Solution Explorer and either turn off the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" check box, or change the radio button to "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies" and select the assemblies that you DO want to reuse types from.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your service reference then there#s an option in the lower part of the window, it says `"Reuse types in referenced assemblies"`.

You can either disable the class reuse for all assemblies or just for specific. Perhaps you should check it out!

[image: configuration dialog]